# 'VkApi' object has no attribute 'messages'

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Программа выдаёт:

> vk.messages.send(
> AttributeError: 'VkApi' object has no attribute 'messages'

В системе всего один vk_api.py и конфликтов никаких вроде не должно быть, а других идей решения у меня и не приходит в голову

При этом коде:

```
    import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import requests
token = *тут был токен*


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)


for event in longpoll.listen():
    
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        

        if event.text == 'Привет' or event.text == 'привет': 
            api = vk.get_api()
            name = api.users.get(user_ids = event.user_id)
            if event.from_user: 
                vk.messages.send( 
                    user_id=event.user_id,
                    message='Привки'
        )
            elif event.from_chat: 
                vk.messages.send( 
                    chat_id=event.chat_id,
                    message='Привет'
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны использовать объект `VkApiMethod` (`api`), вместо объекта `VkApi`, аналогично тому, как получали `name`.

***Пример:***

```py
api = vk.get_api()  # VkApiMethod
name = api.users.get(user_ids=event.user_id)

if event.from_user:
    api.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id, message='Привки')  # vk -> api
elif event.from_chat:
    api.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, message='Привет')  # vk -> api
```